# Old data in database keeps getting replaced by new data

Tags: java, android, sql, database, sqlite

Every time I insert new data into my database, a new row is added but the old rows of data gets replaced by the new one. I can't see any error in my code.

I'll paste below a snippet of my code.

```
private static class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {



    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_TABLE_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}

// Open the database connection.
public DBAdapter open() {
    myDatabase = myDBHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    return this;
}

// Close the database connection.
public void close() {
    myDBHelper.close();
}

// Add a new set of values to the database.
public long insertRow(String name, String date, String time, String duration) {

    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_NAME, name);
    initialValues.put(KEY_DATE, date);
    initialValues.put(KEY_TIME, time);
    initialValues.put(KEY_DURATION, duration);

    // Insert it into the database.
    return myDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);

}

...
```

edit

This is how my database is displayed:

```
 public void displayRecordSet(Cursor cursor) {

    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.LIST);

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            String _id = cursor.getString(DBAdapter.COL_ROWID);
            String date = cursor.getString(DBAdapter.COL_DATE);
            String time = cursor.getString(DBAdapter.COL_TIME);
            String duration = cursor.getString(DBAdapter.COL_DURATION);

                map.put("_id", _id);
                map.put("date", date);
                map.put("time", time);
                map.put("duration", duration);
                mylist.add(map);

           } while(cursor.moveToNext());

        SimpleAdapter myTable = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist, R.layout.row,
        new String[] {"_id", "date", "time", "duration"}, new int[] {R.id.ID, R.id.DATE, R.id.TIME, R.id.DURATION});
        list.setAdapter(myTable);   
    }

    cursor.close();     
}
```

Comment: I can see nothing wrong with the way you are inserting records Perhaps the issue is in the way they are being displayed?

Comment: `the old rows of data gets replaced by the new one` - how do you know?

Comment: I know because the database is displayed on the device I'm using, I'll insert the code that displays the database

Comment: Why exactly are you dropping the table in onUpdate()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in `displayRecordSet()`. You're using the same `map` object for each row in the result set and rewrite values in the `map` over and over again and adding the same map again to the result list. As a result, the result list contains multiple copies of the same map with  values from the last row.

To fix it, create a new object for each iteration in the `do`-`while` loop. For example, move the

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

inside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this：

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        String _id = cursor.getString(DBAdapter.COL_ROWID);
        String date = cursor.getString(DBAdapter.COL_DATE);
        String time = cursor.getString(DBAdapter.COL_TIME);
        String duration = cursor.getString(DBAdapter.COL_DURATION);
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

        map.put("_id", _id);
        map.put("date", date);
        map.put("time", time);
        map.put("duration", duration);
        mylist.add(map);

       } while(cursor.moveToNext());

    SimpleAdapter myTable = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist, R.layout.row,
    new String[] {"_id", "date", "time", "duration"}, new int[] {R.id.ID, R.id.DATE, R.id.TIME, R.id.DURATION});
    list.setAdapter(myTable);   
}
```